# AspNetCoreRateLimit endpoint wild-card does not work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, rate-limiting

I am trying to implement a rate limit using the [AspNetCoreRateLimit package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCoreRateLimit/). I would like to limit the rate on only one endpoint This one:

```
https://[removed for privacy]/v/1/product_provisioning/user_has_signatures?phoneNumber=070930900
```

When I use this config with the `*` wildcard i get the correct rate limiting for all endpoints, but **I would like to implement it only for the endpoint I mentioned above**:

```json
"IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": false,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "GeneralRules": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "*",
            "Period": "60s",
            "Limit": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the following wildcard combinations and none worked:

```json
"Endpoint": "*:/v/1/product_provisioning/*",
```

```json
"Endpoint": "GET:/v/1/product_provisioning/*",
```

```json
"Endpoint": "*:/v/1/product_provisioning/user_has_signatures/*",
```

```json
"Endpoint": "*:/v/1/product_provisioning/user_has_signatures?phoneNumber=*",
```

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#defining-rate-limit-rules): `get:/v/1/product_provisioning/user_has_signatures`

Comment: Tried that it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your  `phoneNumber` is a query string,

```
options.EnableEndpointRateLimiting = true;
options.StackBlockedRequests = false;
options.HttpStatusCode = 429;
options.RealIpHeader = "X-Real-IP";
options.ClientIdHeader = "X-ClientId";
options.GeneralRules = new List<RateLimitRule>
    {
        new RateLimitRule
        {
            Endpoint = "GET:/v/1/product_provisioning/user_has_signatures",
            Period = "60s",
            Limit = 1,
        }
    };
```

In the above code, the option `EnableEndpointRateLimiting` is set as true to ensure that limit is applied to specific endpoints rather than all endpoints. If `EnableEndpointRateLimiting` is set to false then the limits will apply globally and only rules that have as endpoint * will apply.

[image]